# Problems with tuples inside tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tuples, maze

For a tuple of tuples I want to check that all the inner tuples have the same length.

I've tried comparing indexes but it doesn't work.

```
p = ((1,1,1),(1,0,1,1),(1,1,1))

def lab(x):
    if type(x) != tuple:
        return False
    else:
        z = len(x[0])
        for y in x:
            if len(y) < 3 and len(y[1:]) != z:
                return False
            else:
                    while x[0][0] != 1:
                        return False
                    while x[len(x)-1][-1] != 1:
                        return False
        else:
            return True

print(lab(p))
```

Basically, you can see the 2nd tuple has 4 elements and not 3 and i just wanted the function to return false and not True, since the 2nd tuple has a size different than the 1st and it should return false since that happaned.

Im trying to build a maze and its squared and like all squares all the parts have the same size so i need all the tuples to have the same length, the first digit of the 1st tuple has to be 1 and the last digit of the last tuple to be 1 too in order to build this maze.

Ps: I just need the length part the rest is taken care of, but if u have any ideas on how to improve this im all ears.

Comment: Sorry, from your question I cannot understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: You seem to be using `while` when you mean `if`.

Comment: At the very first glance, at least `return "False"` does not make much sense and should probably be replaced by `return False`.

Comment: Why doesn't the `else:` block use `y`?

Comment: You can `assert len(set([len(tup) for tup in x])) == 1` and then do the rest of the work. Are you asking for help for the rest of the work? Or just the length check?

Comment: the length check i just want to check if all tuples have the same size and where do i put this ```` assert len(set([len(tup) for tup in x])) == 1 ```` exactly do i replace it with any specific line?

Comment: @MartimCorreia you can put it at the very top if you want to raise an assertion error. If not, use the one liner from my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this with a one-liner:

```
def lab(tups):
  return len(set([len(tup) for tup in tups])) == 1

print(lab(((1,1,1),(1,0,1,1),(1,1,1)))) # False
print(lab(((1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1)))) # True
```

... Of course, you probably want to add error checks for empty tuples, etc

Comment: There's some other condition he wants to check, not just the same length.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that all the inner tuples/lists have the same length:

```
>>> f = lambda l: all([len(t) == len(l[0]) for t in l])
>>> f([(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1)])
True
>>> f([(1,1,1),(1,0,1,1),(1,1,1)])
False
>>> f([])
True
```

Comment: It's still not checking if the inner tuples have the same length

Comment: that's exaclty what `len(t) == len(l[0])` is for